# How to run "b.php" file from "a.php" using cli command in php code

Tags: php, command-line-interface

How to run "b.php" file from "a.php" using cli command in php code and return data from "b.php" file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Got any code snippets? What's stopping you from including b.php within a.php?

Comment: I don't want to include b.php file into a.php, On a.php file i have submit the form and after submit i want to trigger b.php file because b.php is a cron file.

Comment: So basically i want to run b.php file whenever a.php file form get submitted. and i want to do this by cli command in php.

Comment: @Atul have you check below code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the PHP documentation for `exec` here http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

If I understand correctly you want to process data on 'a.php' and then trigger another PHP file in the form of b.php. You could probably merge these tasks to make it easier and avoid using `exec` all together, but below should do what you require, this is the a.php file...

```
//Process form data here

echo exec('php b.php');
```

This will return the result of b.php, you can leave the echo off if you don't require an output. It may also be worth looking into `passthru` as well http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

As per the documentation there are some limitations to take into consideration when it comes to PHP Safe mode

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

by `shell_exec()` command you can run whatever you run in command line:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

in your case:

```
//if form submitted
$output = shell_exec('php b.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Include a.php file in b.php file

and then run

D:\xampp\php>php b.php

Comment: I don't want to include b.php file into a.php, On a.php file i have submit the form and after submit i want to trigger b.php file because b.php is a cron file. So basically i want to run b.php file whenever a.php file form get submitted. and i want to do this by cli command in php

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it helps you,

`file_get_contents('b.php');`

this code at end of your a.php file

Comment: Another way use `shell_exec('b.php');`

Comment: `shell_exec()` will execute your `b.php` file in background